# why do i keep getting this error i cant seem to fix it UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: it keeps saying failed to load and i really need this to work]
I one day restarted my computer because it was lagging then i got this error

Comment: Can you show what `yes.unity` is?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ZoVqEhjhWhEn

Comment: clean unity cache and restart it

Comment: i tried it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

To be honest it never happened to me, it says it has a problem with **yes.unity** maybe you should try to recreate the scene or recreate the project.
If the problem persists try reinstalling unity

Comment: I cant just restart 1 month of progress